# Plotly 3D surface with NAs ignores some points

Tags: r, plotly

I am new to this website so forgive me for any formatting issues.

I am trying to plot a 3D surface using plotly add_surface(), from data with NAs values. The output is mostly good, however because of those NAs, other points between the border of the plot and the NAs are not plotted along with the NAs themselves.

Here is an example dummy data set to illustrate my point:

```
x = seq(1,2,length.out=10)
y = seq(0,1,length.out=10)
z = matrix(rep(x,each = length(y)), nrow = length(x))

z[2,8] <- z[2,9] <- z[3,9] <- NA

> z
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [2,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667       NA       NA     2
 [3,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778       NA     2
 [4,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [5,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [6,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [7,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [8,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
 [9,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2
[10,]    1 1.111111 1.222222 1.333333 1.444444 1.555556 1.666667 1.777778 1.888889     2

p <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_surface(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    type="mesh3d"
  )
p
```

The output plot below does not display the points z[1,8:10], z[2,10] and z[3,10], while they are not missing (with no hover info like on the other points).

[image: 3D plotly surface with NAs]

Is there any way to keep the display of those points while leaving out the NAs in plotly add_surface?